# Как сразу отобразить новую загруженную фотографию на сервер во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

На клиенте Vue/Nuxt.js, сервер node.js. Есть коллекция языков с флагами, которая представлена в таблице. У фото есть иконки флагов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По кнопке download(иконка рядом с флагом) я загружаю новую фото/иконку флага на сервер.
Эти данные в таблице я получаю с БД и отображаю в таблице с помощью `computed` свойства. 
Коллекцию языков получаю:

```
async getLanguages() {
      await this.$http
        .get("api/languages")
        .then(response => {
          var result = response.body;
          var dialectArr = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i].dialects) {
              for (let j = 0; j < result[i].dialects.length; j++) {
                dialectArr.push(result[i].dialects[j]);
              }
            }
          }
          dialectArr.forEach(item => {
            result.push(item);
          });
          result.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
            if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
          });
          this.languages = result;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e);
        });
    }
```

Затем уже вывожу сами данные, предварительно разбив их на несколько подмассивов для пагинации:

```
langPaging() {
      let result = [];
      let page = [];
      if (this.languages.length) {
        for (let i = 14; i < this.languages.length; i = i + 15) {
          page = [];
          for (let j = i - 14; j <= i; j++) {
            page.push(this.languages[j]);
          }
          result.push(page);
          if (i + 15 > this.languages.length) {
            page = [];
            for (let m = i + 1; m < this.languages.length; m++) {
              page.push(this.languages[m]);
            }
            result.push(page);
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

После загрузки и сохранения новой фото/иконки соответствующего языка, мне нужно, чтоб оно сразу отобразилось вместо предыдущей фотки. 
Я загружаю все изменения, включая новое фото, так:

```
async sendData(ind) {
      let langObj = new FormData();
      langObj.append('languageName', this.languages[ind].lang)
      langObj.append('languageSymbol', this.languages[ind].symbol)
      langObj.append('languageIso1', this.languages[ind].iso1)
      langObj.append('languageIso2', this.languages[ind].iso2)
      langObj.append('languageActive', this.languages[ind].active)
      langObj.append('dbIndex', this.languages[ind]._id)
      langObj.append("flag", this.file[0]);
      console.log(langObj);
      this.$http
        .post("api/savelanguages", langObj)
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result.data);
          this.languages = [];
          this.getLanguages();          
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      this.languages[ind].crud = false;
    }
```

На сервере код такой:

```
router.post("/savelanguages", upload.fields([{name: "flag"}]), async (req, res) => {
  const flag = req.files["flag"];
  var langID = req.body.dbIndex;
  let languageIcon = await Languages.find({'_id': langID});
  let icon = './dist' + languageIcon[0].icon;
  if (flag) {
    moveLangIcon(flag[0], icon)
  }
  var objForUpdate = {
    lang: req.body.languageName,
    symbol: req.body.languageSymbol,
    iso1: req.body.languageIso1,
    iso2: req.body.languageIso2,
    active: req.body.languageActive
  };
  console.log(objForUpdate);
  Languages.update({"_id": langID}, objForUpdate).then(result => {
    res.send(result);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.send('Something went wrong :(');
  });
});
```

Сама таблица:

```
table
    tr
      th(v-for="(headItem, key) in table.head" :class='"th__col-" + (key + 1)') {{ headItem.title }}
        ISO(v-if="key == 3" :titlesp1="titlesp1Value" titlesp2="(two letters)")
        ISO1(v-if="key == 4" :titlesp3="titlesp2Value" titlesp4="(three letters)")
    .bodyWrapper
      tr.rbody(v-for="(language, ind) in langPaging[currentPage-1]" :class='"tr__row-" + (ind + 1)' )
        td.data1(:class="{outliner: language.crud}")
          button.languageicons(:style='{backgroundImage: "url(" + language.icon + ")"}' :class="[{icos_special: ind == 3},{video_special: ind == 5},{more_special: ind == 6}]")
          button.upload1(v-if="language.crud")
          .iconPreview(v-if="language.crud")
            input.upload(v-if="language.crud" @change="uploadFile" :readonly="true" type="file" name="uploadedFileIcon")
            .preview(v-if="imageData.length > 0")
              img(:src="imageData")
        td.data2(:class="{outliner: language.crud}")
          input.inprow2(v-model="language.lang" :readonly="!language.crud" )
          input.inprow2(v-model="language._id" type="hidden")
        td.data3
          input.inprow2(v-model="language.symbol" :readonly="true" )
        td.data4
          input.inprow2(v-model="language.iso1" :readonly="true")
        td.data5
          input.inprow2(v-model="language.iso2" :readonly="true")
        td.data6(:class="{outliner: language.crud}")
          input.inprow2(type="checkbox" :disabled="!language.crud" v-model="language.active" :checked="language.crud")
        td.data7
          button.saveB(@click="sendData(ind)" :disabled="!language.crud" :class="{data5_active: !language.crud}")
          button.editB(@click="edit(ind, language)" :class="{data5_active: language.crud}" :disabled="language.crud")
  .paging
    .prev(@click="prevPage" :class='{nonActive: !hasPrev}') 
      span Previous page
    .pageNums(v-for="(arr, num) in langPaging")
      span.pageNums__number(@click="toPage(num)" :class='{current: num == currentPage-1}') {{ num + 1 }}
    .next(@click="nextPage" :class='{nonActive: !hasNext}') 
      span Next page
```

Как этого добиться? Пока получается это только путем обновления всей страницы в браузере.

Comment: А зачем обновлять всю страницу? Почему нельзя вызвать функцию, которая запрашивает эти данные и перезаписать имеющиеся? Добавьте в вопрос код компонента таблицы.

Comment: @Klimenkomud так я вроде так и делаю, но фото остается то же самое.